# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCellContentView' (0x1055f2ff8) to 'UIImageView' (0x1055e3738). (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i've got this error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCellContentView' (0x1055f2ff8) to 'UIImageView' (0x1055e3738). (lldb)
```

at this line in my code:

```
let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
```

Could you help me with this? Searching for two hours now, do not find anything on that specific topic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you put whole code .

Comment: check your tags, I think you gave tag to cell and you try to bind it with imageview

Comment: Basically do not add views programmatically and access them by tag. This is very cumbersome. At least for 2 or 3 Xcode versions you can create custom cells with custom UI elements directly in Interface Builder.

Comment: Error is explicit: `cell?.viewWithTag(1)` is a `UITableViewCellContentView` object, not a `UIImageView` one. Show what look like your implementation of your cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with **contentView** as the contentView is where you add the subview and not directly on the cell.

`let imageView = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView`

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you want:

```
let imageView = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
```

Your UIImageView, and any other custom views added to the cell,  should be added to the cell's contentView.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview